# Layouting div besides a div classes with float and center

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day! So far I have used the float functions `right` and `left` but somehow I stuck and can't advance. I want to have a center div where there a div floating within the center div in right and left.

Here's what I achieved so far:

```html
<style type="text/css">
#wrap{
 width:485px;
}
.left {
 width:240px;
 background-color: #00d;
 height:123px;
 float: left;
}

.right {
 width:240px;
 background-color: #00d;
 height:123px;
 float: right;
}

</style>

<div id="wrap">
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

and lastly. Here's what I want to achieve.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hi Abegail; it's unclear what you're asking. You have two divs in your markup that are floated left and right... but your image shows a third div in the center. Do you want that "center" div to be a sibling of the left and right ones, or simply be the background of the parent `.wrap` div?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I won't use floats for what you will like to approach. Instead I will use `display: flex` on the `wrap` element. Example:

```css
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-item {
  background-color: #00d;
  height: 123px; 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="wrap-item left">LEFT</div>
  <div class="wrap-item center">CENTER</div>
  <div class="wrap-item right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Also, note the usage of percentages on the width to get some sort of responsiveness (adaptive to different screens widths).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than float, use [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which makes vertical alignment and other justification much simpler. Then use [CSS Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) to rotate your text.

```css
#wrap{
  width:600px;
  height:150px;
  display:flex;  /* The container will be laid out as a flex box */
  align-items:stretch; /* Makes the childre use all the height of the parent */
}
#wrap > div {
  background-color: #00d;
  margin:3px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  width:25%; 
  display:flex; /* The children can also be laid out as flex box containers  */
  align-items:center; /* Alignment along the "cross-axis" (vertical here) */
  justify-content:center; /* Alignment along "main-axis" (horizontal here) */
  font-size:2em;
}

/* Override the width for just the center item */
#wrap > div.center { width:50%; }

.rotate { transform:rotate(45deg);} /* Rotate the element */
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
 <div><div class="rotate">LEFT</div></div>
 <div class="center">CENTER</div>
 <div><div class="rotate">RIGHT</div></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Good one, I don't believe he wanted to rotate the text, but it is nice to show how to do it anyway. +1

Comment: @Shidersz Look at the bottom of his question. He is showing that `Left` and `Right` are rotated.

Comment: I have seen it, but as there is no mention describing that on the question, personally I assume he put it that way because they don't fit horizontally and was just to help describe his layout. Anyway, like I say, it is nice too see how to do it.