# How to create variables in javascript for background-position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a variable for my background-position in Javascript/CSS. I am very new to programming, and a developer friend of mine wrote the original code and I am having trouble assigning my background-position to a variable.

```
<style>
.frame{
  width: 354.1875px;
  var viewWidth = 354.1875px;
  height: 415px;
  background-image: url(https://website.com/image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 50%;
}
.frame1 {
  background-position: -1*viewWidth 50%;
}
.frame2 {
  background-position: -2*viewWidth 50%;
} 
.frame3 {
  background-position: -600px 50%;
}
```

Frames 1 and 2 are where I have tried to use my variable, from what I've googled it should work, can someone please help me here?

Comment: that is just CSS code. CSS doesn't know about Javascript code

Comment: CSS doesn't have variables.

Comment: Hello new contributor! No worries, we are here to help. As you can already see, the word `variables` sounds a bit odd in this question. Perhaps you could provide us the HTML as well, which is connected to your posted CSS. So far Javascript is not part of your question. Let us know!

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented, I don't know what I found on Google I guess... I have a little experience in Python and C but Javasript/JQuery/CSS all confuse me haha

Comment: @ScottMarcus CSS has had variable support for years https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/

Comment: @TylerH That's a CR. It's not standard until it's a Recommendation. In many cases, CRs move backwards in the standardization process, they get abandoned for some other approach, or they might get rolled into a larger spec, so you use them at your own risk.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The R in CR stands for Recommendation. Specs at that stage may get some adjustments made (and that's to be expected) but the very purpose of the spec is not going to go away. It's therefore wrong to say that CSS doesn't have variables when there's been a CSS Variables spec that made it to CR *four years ago*. It's also disingenuous to give this warning on the Qs and As of others but [not your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090434/layouting-div-besides-a-div-classes-with-float-and-center/55090708#55090708)

Answer (score 1):

You're maybe thinking of [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) which you could use in the following way.

> Custom properties (sometimes referred to as CSS variables or cascading
>   variables) are entities defined by CSS authors that contain specific
>   values to be reused throughout a document.

```css
:root {
  --viewWidth: 354.1875px;
}

.frame{
  width: var(--viewWidth);
  height: 415px;
  background-image: url(https://website.com/image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 50%;
}
.frame1 {
  background-position: calc(-1 * var(--viewWidth)) 50%;
}
.frame2 {
  background-position: calc(-2 * var(--viewWidth)) 50%;
} 
.frame3 {
  background-position: -600px 50%;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this is not a standard and support for it as well as its implementation are subject to change.